# Browserify window object does not have globals

Tags: javascript, global-variables, browserify

I need to add a global library of the form:

```
window.Foo = function() {
  api = {};
  api.myVar = GLOBALS;
  return api;
}
```

to my project using an external script tag. `GLOBALS` is another variable added to `window` from another library that `window.FOO` depends on. However, when I access `window` in one of my Browserify modules, `window.Foo` is not there. If I try shimming `window.FOO`, then its global dependencies are not available to it. I can see and use `window.Foo` from chrome inspector, though. How do I get the "real" window object in a module? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The project was a chrome extension and it was being sandboxed. It had nothing to do with Browserify.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like below pattern, where the `Foo` will gets attached to whatever object `this` is pointing to in all environments. Like in browser, it will add it to `window`

```
(function(global) {
    global.Foo = function() {
         return {};
    }
})(this);
```

Comment: I edited my answer a little bit. This did not work because `window.Foo` also depends on globals added to the window object.

Comment: I tested my code, it works both in browser and node. If `Foo` is dependent on other globals, please expand the question, for more information.

Comment: okay, I've updated my question again. Hopefully this addresses all of the problems.

Comment: First try accessing just `GLOBALS` by using `console.log` or any other api, to confirm, whether it is loading it properly or not, if not. There can be two solutions, since it is a client script, edit/replace all `window` identifier with `this` in the 3 party script. Or, 2nd solution is execute/add `window = this;` script before all the script, using this make all other script to refer environment_global with window property irrespective of any environment. Atlast if GLOBALS uses DOM apis, then re-write it, I don't think there is any other way for that.

Comment: hm, I cannot rewrite due to the nature of the project, unfortunately. I guess I'll have to just drop browserify.

Comment: Hmmm,.. will update if I find any other possible solution :)